# Ellipses in GNOME status bar?

Tags: gnome

Recently whenever I wake my computer up from standby, the status bar in GNOME ends up like this:

[image: Ellipses in status bar]

I have no idea why this happens, the ellipses won't go away no matter what until I perform a reboot. Furthermore, the dots are pushing some other indicators (such as a clock) off the screen on the right.

I've tried disabling and re-enabling about all my GNOME extensions to no avail.

Has anyone seen anything like this before?

Comment: What if you restart GNOME Shell (Alt-F2, type `r`, Enter)?

Comment: That works! Didn't know you could restart gnome shell like this :) But still it's weird that this happens